# Is there a Canadian equivalent to Forestry Rangers

Tags: hiking, backpacking, legality, canada

In the States, we have a Ranger structure, whereby you can call a ranger district that can answer questions about that district.  Similarly, you can call higher up the food chain for questions affecting larger areas.

Is there an equivalent government entity in Canada?

Comment: Is that something specifically for public land?  From my limited time in Canada I've learned about *crown land* and *Public land usage zones (PLUZ)*.

Comment: In the States it is, yes.  I'm showing my vast lack of knowledge of all things Canadian by saying that I don't know how it works up there at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the federal level your best bet is either [Parks Canada](http://www.pc.gc.ca/eng/index.aspx) or 
the [Canadian Forest Service](http://www.nrcan.gc.ca/forests), which is part of [Natural Resources Canada](http://www.nrcan.gc.ca/), which also has tons of other relevant areas such as maps and map data.

At the provincial level there is [a whole gamut of environment, forestry and fishery departments](http://www.canadian-forests.com/provincial_governments.html).